# Phpmailer, errors when try to send

Tags: php, post, phpmailer

php is not my cup of tea,  but unfortunately I need to create a mail form with attachment to my website.

I fallowed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydQT6Bt4zIk&t=33s, but got some errors.  It's looks like that my input values are not decelerated.
I used ' $_POST['name of html input '];' to get it.

project:
http://mork.webd.pl/uploads/mail-form/mail-form.7z

list of errors:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp2\htdocs\vomo\send.php on line 15

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp2\htdocs\vomo\send.php on line 57
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Message body empty in C:\xampp2\htdocs\vomo\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:1580 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\vomo\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1488): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->preSend() #1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\vomo\send.php(58): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #2 {main}
```

```
my php code:
```

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);



$name = $_POST['name-of'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['mess-content'];







try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 10;
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Mailer="smtp";
    $mail->Host=gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    $mail->Username ='xowlasky@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password="xxxx";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port=465;

    $mail->setFrom("xowlasky@gmail.com", $_POST['name-of']);
    $mail->addAddress("jaroslaw.mor@gmail.com");

//attachment

if(array_key_exists('attachment',$_FILES)) {

    $img_name  = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    $upload = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),  hash('sha256' , $_FILES['attachment']['name'] ));

    $uploadFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Images/'.$img_name;
    if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['attachment']['tmp-name'],  $uploadFile)){
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadFile, "My Attachment");

    }

   


}
$mail -> Subject ='Zapytanie ze strony www';
$mail->Body = "<h3>Name : $name <br>Email : $email <br>Message : $message</h3>";
$mail->send();
header("Location: sent.php");
exit();


}

catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
}
```

my HTML code of form

```
    <label for="fname">Imię i Nazwisko <span class="star">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Podaj imię i nazwisko..." pattern="^([A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ][a-zżźćńółęąś{3,}]+)(\s|-|_)+([A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ][a-zżźćńółęąś]+)$" required>
    

    <label for="fname">e-mail <span class="star">*</span></label>
    <input type="mail" id="mailadress" name="mail" placeholder="wprowadź adres email..." pattern="^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*(\.\w{2,})+$"  required>
    


    <label for="text">Telefon</label>
    <div class="form-info">wprowadź numer telfonu w formie +xx xxx xxx xxx</div>
    <input type="text" id="phone-number" name="phone" placeholder="podaj nr telefonu..."  pattern="/^[+]?\d{1,3}\s?(-)?[0-9]{3}(\s)?[0-9]{3,4}(\s)?[0-9]{3}(\s)?$/">





    <label for="subject">Treść wiadomości:<span class="star">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-info">pole musi zawierać minimum 10 znaków</div>
    <textarea id="message" name="mess-content" placeholder="Treść wiadomości..." style="height:300px" pattern=".{10,}" required></textarea>
   
    
    <br>

    '<div class="alert alert-success"></div>

    <div class="error-message "></div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Wyślij">
    <input id="upload" name="attachment" id="upload-file" type="file" >
</div>
      

</form>
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzxh937b/

Comment: Almost certainly your `input` names don't match the names the PHP is looking for, but since you haven't posted your HTML we can't check.

Comment: 1st input from top(Imie i Nazwisko)   input type="text" id="name" name="name" 


2nd (e-mail) type="mail" id="mailadress" name="mail"

3rd(Telefon) <input type="text" id="phone-number" name="phone"


4th <textarea id="message" name="mess-content"

Comment: Your HTML email input element has `name="mail"`, while your PHP script expects the name `$_POST['email']` (missing "e" prefix). Hence the raised "undefined array key" warning.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jeroen said, the name of your input email is not the same in your php code. Change your email input name into this.

```
<input type="mail" id="mailadress" name="email" placeholder="wprowadź adres email..." pattern="^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*(\.\w{2,})+$"  required>
```